# Fetching data with retrofit with try/catch

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, retrofit

My task is to fetch list of clients from retrofit. I tried with List but I wanted to include generic class Result. This is in Android app.

This is my api:

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
 @GET("/clients")
 suspend fun getClientsData(): ClientResponse
```

ClientsResponse:

```
    data class ClientResponse(
        val success: Boolean,
        val message: String
    )
```

RepositoryImp:

```
override suspend fun getClientsData(): Result<String> {
        return try {
            val clients = clientTrackerApi.getClientsData()
            if (clients.success){
                Result.Success( errorMessage = "Clients fetched")
            }
            else{
                Result.Error(errorMessage = clients.message)
            }
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Result.Error(errorMessage = e.message ?: "Problem")
        }
    }
```

Generic result class:

```
sealed class Result<T>(val data: T? = null, val errorMessage: String? = null) {
    class Success<T>(data: T? = null, errorMessage: String? = null) : Result<T>(data, errorMessage)
    class Error<T>(data: T? = null, errorMessage: String) : Result<T>(data, errorMessage)
    class Loading<T> : Result<T>()
}
```

How can I return Result which has id, name, age etc.
Because I want to further map it to ClientEntity and store list of clients to database.

Answer (score 0):

First of All:
Model Class create according to JSON respose:
For example:
{"success":true, "Message":"OK", "data":[{"name":"name-exm","age":7}]}
Model Class:

```
    data class ClientResponse(val success: Boolean, val message: String,val data : List<Client>?){
    data class Client( val name: String?, val age: Int?)
}
```

retrun data in result:

```
override suspend fun getClientsData(): Result<String> {
    return try {
        val clients = clientTrackerApi.getClientsData()
        if (clients.success){
            Result.Success( data= clients , errorMessage = "Clients fetched")
        }
        else{
            Result.Error(errorMessage = clients.message)
        }
    }
    catch (e: Exception){
        Result.Error(errorMessage = e.message ?: "Problem")
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error now;
 Type mismatch.
Required:
String
Found:
List<Client>

Comment: Send json. 
then i provide a complete best code for it.